# video views count of a video posted to twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter, twitter-gem

I need to access the video views count of a video posted to Twitter account through Twitter API console.
Is it possible to get the video views count?
I am using Twitter gem in rails to acces the metircs of posts done in Twitter.

Please suggest!

Answer (score 0):

So far, the https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/labs/tweet-metrics/overview only works for twit owners or authorized developer accounts and the enterprise API is expensive.